# Multiple issues in my AndroidManifest.xml with my flutter App

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I want to launch my App to the Playstore.
So I changed my minSdkVersion in the app\build.gradle from 16 to 31.
But now, when I build my Appbundle I encountered this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.example.debt.MainActivity>.
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding compon
> ent has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.debt">
   <application
        android:label="Money Reminder"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:debt/colors.dart';
import 'package:debt/add.dart';
import 'package:debt/data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
late Box box;

List<Data>datalist=[];
Future <void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Hive.initFlutter();

  Hive.registerAdapter(DataAdapter());
  box = await Hive.openBox("infos");
  //wandelt die daten für die Anzeige um
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> data2 = box.toMap();

  //macht aus map liste
  data2.forEach((key, value) {
    if(kDebugMode){
      Data w =Data (key, value);
      datalist.add(w);
    }


  });

runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: debt(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

));}
// ignore: camel_case_types
class debt extends StatefulWidget {
  const debt({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _debtState createState() => _debtState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _debtState extends State<debt> {

  Map<String, dynamic> values = {};
  String text = 'Text';
  double w = 100;
  double h = 20;
  Widget quoteTemplate(data){
    return ValueListenableBuilder<Box>(
        valueListenable: Hive.box('infos').listenable(),
        builder: (context, box, widget) {
          return
      Card(
        

      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 0),
      child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // x Achse
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,    // y Achse
          children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, // x Achse
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,// y Achse

        children: <Widget>[
          Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 100,
            height: h,
            child: Text(
              data.people,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize:  18,
                color: Colors.grey[600],
              )

            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 6,),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,

            child: Text(
                data.money,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize:  14,
                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                )

            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
            ,Container(//delete
              alignment: Alignment.center,

              child: TextButton(style: TextButton.styleFrom(

              ),
                onPressed: (){
        box.delete(data.people);
        setState(() {
          Map<dynamic, dynamic> data2 = box.toMap();
          datalist=[];
          data2.forEach((key, value) {
              if(kDebugMode){
                Data w =Data (key, value);
                datalist.add(w);
              }
          });
        });
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.delete,color: lightblue,),
              ),
            ),
            Container(//minusbutton
              alignment: Alignment.center,

              child: TextButton(style: TextButton.styleFrom(//Minus Butten

              ),
                onPressed: (){
                  var zwischenspeicher = box.get(data.people);

                  double zwischenspeicher2= double.parse(zwischenspeicher) - 1.0;
                  var schulden = zwischenspeicher2.toString();



                  box.put(data.people,schulden);
                  //Updatet das widget
                  setState(() {
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> data2 = box.toMap();
                    datalist=[];
                    data2.forEach((key, value) {
                      if(kDebugMode){
                        Data w =Data (key, value);
                        datalist.add(w);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.remove,color: darkblue,),
              ),
            ),
            Container(//plus Button
              alignment: Alignment.center,

              child: TextButton(style: TextButton.styleFrom(

              ),
                onPressed: (){
                  var zwischenspeicher = box.get(data.people);

                  var zwischenspeicher2= double.parse(zwischenspeicher) + 1;
                  var schulden = zwischenspeicher2.toString();



          box.put(data.people,schulden);

                  setState(() {
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> data2 = box.toMap();
                    datalist=[];
                    data2.forEach((key, value) {
                      if(kDebugMode){
                        Data w =Data (key, value);
                        datalist.add(w);
                      }
                    });
                  });
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add,color: darkbrown,),
              ),
            ),
          ],
      ),
    );});
  }Widget buttond(){
    return
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Expanded(child: Align(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
        child:

        FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(context);
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),backgroundColor: lightbrown,


    ),),),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: lightblue ,
        title: const Text("Money Reminder"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:

      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
        Column(
          children: datalist.map((data)=> quoteTemplate(data)).toList(),
    ),

          ],
        ),
      ),bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,0,20,10),
      child:


        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(context);
          },
          //child: const Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),

          child: const Text('add/edit debt',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,fontFamily: "Futura",color: Colors.white),),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom( backgroundColor:lightbrown,)


        )

    ),



    );
  }


void _awaitReturnValueFromSecondScreen(BuildContext context) async {

  // start the SecondScreen and wait for it to finish with a result
  final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const add(),
      ));

  // after the SecondScreen result comes back update the Text widget with it
  setState(() {
    datalist = result;
  });
  }
}
```

`

```
The Problems of the manifest:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcZWN.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lkfx.png


I tryed to Invalidate the cashe.
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file `activity`.

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge">
```

Comment: Thanks for help but I have still the same problem.